# Row equivalency of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M$ be an $n\times m$ matrix and let $N$ be an invertible $n\times n$ matrix. Why is it that the matrix $NM$ is row equivalent to $M$? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $N$ is [invertible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix), then it is equal to the product of a finite sequence of [elementary matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix): $$N=E_1 E_2 \cdots E_n.$$

Hence $$NM=E_1 E_2 \cdots E_n M.$$  Multiplying by an elementary matrix is equivalent to performing a row operation.

---

To prove the first claim: If $N$ is invertible, then it is row equivalent to the identity matrix.  So, there is a finite sequence of elementary matrices $A_1,A_2,\ldots,A_k$ for which $A_1 A_2 \cdots A_k N=I$ (we can find them via [Gauss-Jordan Elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)).  This implies $N=(A_k)^{-1} (A_{k-1})^{-1} \cdots (A_1)^{-1}$.  The claim follows since the inverse of an elementary matrix is another elementary matrix.

Comment: Why is it that if $N$ is invertible it is equal to the product of a finite sequence of elementary matrices?